# How Can a CPT in WordPress have a page 2 without an error?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type named `foobar` in my `functions.php` file with a rewrite rule of:

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'foobar',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
```

My page is named `Foobar` and my slug is `foobar`.  The Page is added to the menu and works in the menu.  I can go to the page, see the lorem ipsum posts accordingly.  I click the page and in the URL it shows `site.com/foobar`  however if I have pagination it goes to an error.  If I change my slug in my CPT to:

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'foobars',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
```

Everything works but my url for the page is `site.com/foobar` and the post becomes `site.com/foobars/post` when clicked.  How can I make my posts have `foobar` in the url?  Per my research I show that URL re-writing isn't the best advice but I do not know any other way or am I finding any other way in my search to do what I want to do without the slugs clashing.  How can a rewrite be written so that I can have a matching URL?

Comment: If your CPT rewrite is `foobar` and and your post (page) slug is `foobar` then the URL will be `example.com/foobar/foobar` - if you want a top-level permalink structure you'll need [to implement it](http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic that worked.  Why not post it as an answer with the code so I can give you the rep you deserve?  Plus it would help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CPT rewrite is `foobar` and and your post (page) slug is `foobar` then the URL will be `example.com/foobar/foobar` - if you want a top-level permalink structure you'll need [to implement it](http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/).